# Selecting JFrame without using 'this' command

Tags: java, netbeans, jframe

```
 public main() {
        initComponents();
 JPanel panel=new JPanel();
        panel.setBounds(0, 0, 100, 100);
        panel.setBackground(Jtrue);
        this.add(panel);
}
```

I am able to add Jframe object using this command

However, when I write this in a separate method, I cannot add because the 'this' method is inside that object.

```
   public void created(){
        
        
        int degisken=1;
        JPanel panel=new JPanel();
        panel.setBounds(0, 0, 100, 100);
        panel.setBackground(Jtrue);
        this.add(panel);
       
      
      
    }
```

How can I select that jframe instead of 'this'

I don't want to create a new jframe because there is already one

Comment: You can use `SwingUtilties.windowForComponent(....)` to get the top level container for a given component.

Answer (score 1):

You should create you JFrame instance in a way that it will be visible in your whole class.

You can achieve this by declaring a JFrame as a private member of your class. Then you will be able to access it in all class methods:

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class JFrameDemo {
private JFrame frame;

```
public JFrameDemo() {
    this.frame=new JFrame("Demo #1");
    initComponents();
    created();
}

private void initComponents() {
    // Do your stuff here
}

public void created() {
    int degisken = 1;
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setBounds(0, 0, 100, 100);
    panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(640, 480));
    panel.setBackground(new Color(255, 128, 112));
    this.frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
    this.frame.pack();
    this.frame.setVisible(true);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrameDemo frameDemo = new JFrameDemo();
}
```

}

Another solution is that your class extends JFrame. This way, you will access the JFrame instance using the `this` keyword because `this` is your class and thus your JFrame:

```
import java.awt.Color;
```

import java.awt.Dimension;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class JFrameDemo2 extends JFrame {

```
public JFrameDemo2() {
    super("Demo #2");
    initComponents();
    created();
}

private void initComponents() {
    // Do your stuff here
}

public void created() {
    int degisken = 1;
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setBounds(0, 0, 100, 100);
    panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(640, 480));
    panel.setBackground(new Color(255, 128, 112));
    this.getContentPane().add(panel);

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrameDemo2 frameDemo = new JFrameDemo2();
    frameDemo.pack();
    frameDemo.setVisible(true);
}
```

}

Another remark: don't add your component directly on your JFrame but on the underlying container:

```
yourFrameInstance.getContentPane().add(yourComponentInstance)
```